# Alternative for google code site

Tags: issue-tracking

Google will shutdown google code site in the near future. It's a pity.

I am searching the alternative for google site.

I would like to do in the new site

1. put wiki information
2. put source code
3. issue management

Are there any recommendations?

For wiki and source code, I can use github, bitbucket etc. 
But for issue management, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub will actually [do issue management for you](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/) - all you have to do is hit the checkbox marked "Issues" (under the "Features" heading) while creating your repository.

GitHub's issue management system is actually really well integrated with the rest of GitHub - for instance, you can close issues from commits you make to the repository.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not noticed the issue management system in github. I will try to use it.